# MS SQL - reading multiple tables in C# atomically

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, transactions, sqltransaction

Imagine, there is a program, written in `C#`, in which there is an `object (A)` which references 2 sets of `objects ( set of B, set of C)`.

These objects are stored in `MS SQL` as rows in `TableA`, `TableB`, `TableC`

where

```
TableA has a field ID_Of_B referencing TableB as foreign key in a M:M relationship
TableC has a field ID_Of_A referencing TableA as foreign key in a M:1 relationship
```

(therefore, a single object A = 1 row in `TableA`, and it can be linked to multiple rows in `TableB` and `TableC`)

the question I'm trying to ask is, if I want to use `C#` to select the current `B objects` and `C objects` linked to `object A` (of a particular ID in `TableA`), how do I use `SqlTransaction` to do it in such a way the select statement will retrieve the values that are accurate?

I tried to do it with 3 different select statements `(select from A)`, then `(select from B)`, then `(select from C)`, but within these 3 select statements either of the 2 tables could have changed information and the result set may not be accurate.

TLDR: how to use `c# SqlTransaction` to guarantee a select which pulls multiple table data in 1:M and M:M relationships in an atomic and accurate manner (does not let other simultaneous update / delete statements in tables B and C affect the integrity of the result set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [SqlTransaction.IsolationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to guarantee consistency.  Either `Snapshot` or `Serializable` should work, depending exactly on your use case.